# What is the difference between width and pixelWidth in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What is the difference? isn't the width calculated in pixels as well? How should I know which one to use?

Comment: there are several width and pixelWidth properties. which one are you talking about? and how does the manual not help you here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several properties in corona , and let me show you some of the important **Content Properties** , according to official documentation [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling), Read through whole **Project Configuration** documentation [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling) , and you will understand the whole picture.

`display.contentWidth` and `display.contentHeight`( This will default to the screen width, but may be another value if you are using content scaling in config.lua) — read-only properties representing the **original** width and height of the content, **in pixels**.

`display.pixelWidth` and `display.pixelHeight`(This value is in pixels and is always relative to **portrait orientation**) — read-only properties representing the **entire screen** width and height, **in pixels**.

`display.viewableContentWidth` and `display.viewableContentHeight`(contains height and width of whole viewable screen) — read-only properties representing the **viewable** width and height. This is useful if you're using **zoomEven scaling**, as it will reveal the viewable (**uncropped**) measurements, in pixels.

`display.actualContentWidth` and `display.actualContentHeight`(The result depends on the scale setting) — read-only properties representing the width and height in **Corona** content units of the screen. The result depends on the scale setting.
For **letterbox scale**, returns the content height and width, including the letterbox area.
For **zoomEven** scale, returns a value matching the **display.viewableContentHeight** and **display.viewableContentWidth** property.

`display.contentCenterX` and `display.contentCenterY` — read-only properties representing the **center** of the content area, useful for positioning objects along either central axis.